# Give an example of a group $G$ such that $G/Z(G)$ is not abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

> Give an example of a group $G$ such that $G/Z(G)$ is not abelian.

I am having trouble understanding what the group $G/Z(G)$ looks like. Because of that I am having troubles answering the above question.

Comment: What is $S_3 / Z(S_3)$?

Comment: $G/Z(G)$ is abelian (including trivial) if and only if $G$ is nilpotent of class at most $2$. So pick any group that is not nilpotent (of class 0, 1, or~2) and you're done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $:$ Take $G=S_3.$ What is $Z(S_3)$?

Note that in order to show that $G/Z(G)$ is non-abelian we need only to find two elements $\sigma,\tau \in G$ such that $\sigma \tau {\sigma}^{-1} {\tau}^{-1} \notin Z(G).$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For any group $G$, we have $$G/Z(G)\cong \operatorname{Inn}(G),$$ where $\operatorname{Inn}(G)$ is the group of [inner automorphisms](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_automorphism) of $G$.

Comment: See Chapter 9 of Gallian's *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra"*.